# Telerik RadGrid not being filtered by ComboBox

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Grid that shoud be filtered when the selection of the ComboBox changes:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
<telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="QsfFromDecorator" runat="server" DecoratedControls="All" EnableRoundedCorners="false" />

<label for="NamesDDL">Select plant name to view its reports:</label>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="NamesDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="dllDataSource"
        DataTextField="PlantNameAndID" DataValueField="PlantID" Width="250px" Height="150px"
        AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" Value="0" Selected="true"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
</div>

<div style="margin: 15px 0 20px;">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="OrdersGrid" AllowPaging="true" DataSourceID="gridSource" runat="server"
        GridLines="None" AllowSorting="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dllDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Dev-TestOilConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="select customer.plant.PlantID, customer.plant.PlantNo, customer.plant.PlantName, customer.plant.PlantID, cast(customer.plant.PlantID as varchar) + ' - ' + customer.plant.PlantName as PlantNameAndID from customer.plant where plant.CustID = 10 order by plant.PlantNo"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="gridSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Dev-TestOilConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="select LabID, SampleDate, MachCond, LubCond, CustReview, CustReviewDte, machine.PlantID from customer.plant inner join customer.machine on machine.PlantID = plant.PlantID inner join sample.sample on sample.PointID = machine.PointID where ((machine.PlantID = @PlantID and @PlantID <> 0) or (machine.PlantID = machine.PlantID and @PlantID = 0)) and plant.custid = 10">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PlantID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ControlID="NamesDDL"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="NamesDDL">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="OrdersGrid" LoadingPanelID="AjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="NamesDDL"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

The data binding works fine initially, the grid displays all records unfiltered.  When I change the selection in the ComboBox, the grid reloads, but doesn't filter the data.  Any thoughts on why this isn't working?  Or how I could take a different approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of it looks good to me. Maybe try giving an alias to customer.plant.PlantID as PlantID. Also, you have that same column in your dllDataSource two times.

Something like this:

```
SelectCommand="select customer.plant.PlantID as PlantID, customer.plant.PlantNo, customer.plant.PlantName, cast(customer.plant.PlantID as varchar) + ' - ' + customer.plant.PlantName as PlantNameAndID from customer.plant where plant.CustID = 10 order by plant.PlantNo"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```